# How to identify which NFS client generates disk IO?

Tags: nfs, nfs4

Our pool server disk is 100% busy.

I checked with `iotop` and determined that `nfsd` is the top process which consumes disk IO.

I need to narrow that down further and want to determine which of the NFS clients using the server is/are responsible for this disk IO bottleneck. How do I proceed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: iftop will show you which client generates most of the network traffic. Very likely it will be the same client which generates the IO load.

Comment: inspired by your question, I have build a **nfstop** to monitor shuch activity https://github.com/kofemann/nfstop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iotop` and then `o` - you will see which process reads and/or writes and how much to the HDD.

Check the pid of that process and do `netstat -entp | grep <pid>` - that way you will see established tcp connection and from which address it's coming. Use `enp` to check for both tcp and udp sessions.

You can also do a `netstat -anp | grep 2049` - that way getting an ip address and pid, then correlate the pid to the one from `iotop`.

Comment: It couldn't find anything when I run netstat -entp | grep <pid>. But I have a process with this pid

Comment: Then try `netstat -encp | grep <pid>` - the `c` switch will show continuous output.

Comment: I've tried with `netstat -anp | grep 2049` command, but it doesn't help.

Comment: `netstat -anp` unfortunately doesn't show the PID for processes that use NFS. `iotop` doesn't distinguish between NFS I/O and other I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the client using most IO will also doing most network traffic, so what I do is: dump all traffic for a few seconds, and then create a sorted list of the hosts (limited to the nfs hosts) that used most traffic:

```
tcpdump > dump.cap  # (30 secs should be enought), press ctr+ c
grep -o "<something iding an nfs client>" dump.cap | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```